# Why can I not check for comparisons on strings without them being lists?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, palindrome

I was working on the popular palindrome question in python. I originally thought this code would be enough:

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    rev_str = reversed(input_string)

    if rev_str == input_string:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

But only some of the examples ended up being correct. I checked the solution and I had to change the strings into lists for the code to work properly but I don't understand why.

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    rev_str = reversed(input_string)

    if list(rev_str) == list(input_string):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Any help on understanding why this is the case would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that reversed("hello") returns a reversed iterator object, not "olleh." This is to save memory, as it doesn't need to compute all the letters until you need them.

```
>>> reversed("hello")
<reversed object at 0x02A7B170>
```

If this confuses you, look into what iterators are.

If you want to reverse a string, you can just do

```
s[::-1]
```

Where s is your string.